# Self text writing animation using android

Tags: android, flash, animation, opengl-es

I am trying to implement a self text writing animation (preferably using custom fonts, cursive handwriting, etc) in android. How can I go about doing that? The url below has the animation I need.

http://s449.photobucket.com/user/ine07jasoncasesmom/media/edge---self-writing-text.gif.html

Comment: Which technology? Java? Flash?

Comment: I already have a functioning app and I want to use this animation for the splash screen (home page). So if there is a way to embed flash into an existing android app, that would be great. Else, Java would have to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have flash expirience, you could use AndEngine- basicaly it's rather for games but it have effects similar to flash (and AndEngine api is quite similar to flash) and it use Opengl es https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter